# Discovering GUI failure in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have discovered my JavaFX application does not work on Windows 10 - the GUI draws blank. I can fix the issue by forcing JAvaFX to use software rendering by running jar with the `-Dprism.order=sw`.

For this solution I have to know it'll fail ahead of time. Is there a recommended way to check this from a running application and 'redraw' with software rendering if drawing failure is found?

Update:
Prism.verbose output below. I think prism 'thinks' it is drawing correctly. I also notice the 'rollover' pointer icon changes appear in different locations, and links to document downloads don't appear to work. Possibly be hdpi related?

[image: Prism.verbose output]

Comment: I suspect this is not an issue with Windows 10, but an issue with your graphics driver.  I’m not sure how to check for hardware accelerated graphics, but however it’s done, I imagine you’d need to do that check in a [pre-main agent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html).

Comment: try running your code with `-Dprism.verbose=true`, if there is useful output -- you can check for in a script before running your actual app.